# How to generate XML from datatable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I have a datatable from database which contains data as follows

```
ID  NAME    SERVICE                 SITENAME                NODENAME
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED WAN CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER    capitalgatetwrill-ra
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED WAN 2020 BLDG   dxbcontactcentreill-rb
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED WAN 2020 BLDG   dxbcontactcentreill-ra
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED WAN CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER    capitalgatetwrill-rb
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED LAN CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER    capitalgatetwrill-ra
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED LAN 2020 BLDG               dxbcontactcentreill-rb
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED LAN 2020 BLDG               dxbcontactcentreill-ra
27883481    EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES  MANAGED LAN CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER    capitalgatetwrill-rb
27883   EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES MANAGED WAN     CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER    capitalgatetwrill-ra
27883   EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES MANAGED WAN     2020 BLDG               dxbcontactcentreill-rb
27883   EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES MANAGED WAN     2020 BLDG               dxbcontactcentreill-ra
27883   EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES MANAGED WAN     CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER    capitalgatetwrill-rb
```

And i want to create XMl from above data as shown below which is a prototype of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AllSites>
  <SITE_NODES>
    <ID>27883481</ID>
    <NAME>EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES""</NAME>
    <PARTY_SERVICES>
      <SERVICE_NAME>MANAGED WAN</SERVICE_NAME>
      <SERVICE_SITES>
        <SITE_NAME>CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER</SITE_NAME>
        <SITE_NODES>
          <NODE_NAME>capitalgatetwrill-ra</NODE_NAME>
          <NODE_NAME>capitalgatetwrill-rb</NODE_NAME>
        </SITE_NODES>
      </SERVICE_SITES>
      <SERVICE_SITES>
        <SITE_NAME>2020 BLDG</SITE_NAME>
        <SITE_NODES>
          <NODE_NAME>dxbcontactcentreill-rb</NODE_NAME>
          <NODE_NAME>dxbcontactcentreill-ra</NODE_NAME>
        </SITE_NODES>
      </SERVICE_SITES>
    </PARTY_SERVICES>
    <PARTY_SERVICES>
      <SERVICE_NAME>MANAGED LAN</SERVICE_NAME>
      <SERVICE_SITES>
        <SITE_NAME>CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER</SITE_NAME>
        <SITE_NODES>
          <NODE_NAME>abcd-ra</NODE_NAME>
          <NODE_NAME>abcd-rb</NODE_NAME>
        </SITE_NODES>
      </SERVICE_SITES>
      <SERVICE_SITES>
        <SITE_NAME>2021 BLDG</SITE_NAME>
        <SITE_NODES>
          <NODE_NAME>pqms-rb</NODE_NAME>
          <NODE_NAME>pqms-ra</NODE_NAME>
        </SITE_NODES>
      </SERVICE_SITES>
    </PARTY_SERVICES>
  </SITE_NODES>
</AllSites>
```

how to generated it ?DO i need to create an XML template with place holders which should be replaced runtime??or create c# classes and generate it
as follows

```
 public class DetailsBO
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string SERVICE { get; set; }
        public List<SitesBO> sites { get; set; }
    }
    public class SitesBO
    {
        public string SITENAME { get; set; }
        public List<NodesBO> noodes { get; set; }
    }
    public class NodesBO
    {
        public string NODENAME { get; set; }
    }
```

Can somebody give me the c# code

**EDIT**

Suppose if sitename is blank or empty, all are becoming same service type as either WAN or LAN

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SERVICE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SITENAME", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("NODENAME", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "", "capitalgatetwrill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-rb" });
```

Comment: This is ***NOT*** a "gimme-ze-codes" kinda of site - and with your reputation, you should know that. What have **YOU** tried so far? Where are you stuck? We'll **help** - but we won't just **give you** the whole code .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least amount of code is to take the current datatable and output direct to xml.  You could modify code to use Entity which will create classes and the serialize the classes.  But since you already have the datatable I just took table and make xml direct.  It looks like you removed duplicate so I did the same.  I also ordered the results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SERVICE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SITENAME", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("NODENAME", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883481", "EAGLE HILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED LAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-rb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "2020 BLDG", "dxbcontactcentreill-ra" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "27883", "EAGLE DRILLS PROPERTIES", "MANAGED WAN", "CAPITAL GATE-ADNEC LEANING TOWER", "capitalgatetwrill-rb" });

            dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("ID"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("NAME"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("SERVICE"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("SITENAME"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("NODENAME"))
                .CopyToDataTable();


            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><AllSites></AllSites>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement allSites = doc.Root;

            foreach (var idGroup in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ID")))
            {
                XElement siteNode = new XElement("SITE_NODE");
                allSites.Add(siteNode);


                siteNode.Add(new XElement("ID", idGroup.Key));
                siteNode.Add(new XElement("NAME", idGroup.First().Field<string>("NAME")));

                XElement partyServices = new XElement("PARTY_SERVICES");
                siteNode.Add(partyServices);

                partyServices.Add(new XElement("SERVICE_NAME", idGroup.First().Field<string>("SERVICE")));


                foreach (var serviceSite in idGroup.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SITENAME")))
                {
                    XElement serviceSites = new XElement("SERVICE_SITES");
                    partyServices.Add(serviceSites);
                    serviceSites.Add(new XElement("SITE_NAME", serviceSite.Key));

                    XElement siteNodes = new XElement("SITE_NODES");
                    serviceSites.Add(siteNodes);

                    string[] nodeNames = serviceSite.Select(x => x.Field<string>("NODENAME")).Distinct().ToArray();
                    foreach (string nodeName in nodeNames)
                    {
                        siteNodes.Add(new XElement("NODE_NAME", nodeName));
                    }
                }
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference is due to you removing duplicates.  So I added code to sort and remove the duplicates.

Comment: I need to see  the code and exact error.  Not sure what you are doing.

Comment: if SITE_NAME is blank then it is mixing WAN and LAN cases ,because serviceSite.Key is blank.How to avoid it ?do we need to write where clause

Comment: if you are getting data from database, then the error is in the database.  The method you inserted data into database is wrong.  You need to correct the database.